# Error on pod install on all Xcode 11 projects

Tags: cocoapods, xcode11

When I try to install a pod via "pod install", I only get an error on all my projects since Xcode 11.

I've been trying to find a solution for 4 days now, but I can not find anything on Google.

I have already created a completely new clean project, but "pod install" gives me no preference on which pod the same error.

pod env:

```
CocoaPods : 1.8.1 

Ruby : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
RubyGems : 2.5.2.3
    Host : Mac OS X 10.14.4 (18E226)
   Xcode : 11.0 (11A420a)
     Git : git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122)
 Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
 Repositories : master - file system
           trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

Error:

````
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift.git /var/folders/49/k2kb5k6s3kj0qtxrg5tb_c880000gn/T/d20190928-24053-sbmomd --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.8

Cloning into '/var/folders/49/k2kb5k6s3kj0qtxrg5tb_c880000gn/T/d20190928-24053-sbmomd'...
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _curl_global_sslset
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _curl_global_sslset
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib"```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have partially corrected the error. I had to enter these commands in the console:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"

source ~/.bash_profile
```

Afterwards I can do it as long as I do not close the terminal. But how can I set it up permanently?